# How to fetch data from a HTML table of a webpage in Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bioinformatics

This is what i want ,

link "http://tinyurl.com/2bp99mm"

use `"EWQLVLNVWGKVEADIPGHGQEVLIRLFKGHPETLEKFDKFKHLKSEDEMKASEDLKKHGATVLTALGGILKKKGHHEAEIKPLAQSHATKHKIPVKYLEFISECIIQVLQSKHPGDFGADAQGAMNKALELFRKDMASNYKELGFQG"` to blast the protein sequence .

The resultant webpage has a list of link on a table . In the Accesion column there are weblinks that  are my point of interest of interest

I just want the text of the first link that starts with a number and has second character as a alphabet . In the current scenario you will find " 3RGK_A" this is the text i want .

I know i could use `links.add(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")));`  but then how do fulfill the criteria of the link to start with a number and second character to be a Alphabet .

I am lost , new to selenium and python , but trying to learn fast .. Any help will be appreaciated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
import time
import numpy,random
import sys,re

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://tinyurl.com/2bp99mm")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name( "QUERY" )
inputElement.send_keys("EWQLVLNVWGKVEADIPGHGQEVLIRLFKGHPETLEKFDKFKHLKSEDEMKASEDLKKHGATVLTALGGILKKKGHHEAEIKPLAQSHATKHKIPVKYLEFISECIIQVLQSKHPGDFGADAQGAMNKALELFRKDMASNYKELGFQG")##str(seq2))

inputElement.submit()
# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

click_event = driver.find_element_by_link_text("3RGK_A")
click_event.click()
```

i want the program to find that "3RGK_A" is the first link and store the value in a object

Comment: Is your question how do I interact with elements on the page? Or is it how do I write an algorithm in python to create the the input that I want?

Comment: YEs, how do i write an algorithm in Python ? I can interact using the element_by_name in selenium but i donot how to pull this of.

Comment: So I understand your question to be "How do I build a string (of random characters?) where the first character is a number, the second character is any character A-Z, and it should be X number of characters long?"

Comment: yes , if you use the link and enter the sequence that i have mentioned in the description it will take you to the page that has these links . Now the automated program needs to find these links , i have written the code to reach till that point and click that link , but its hard coded , i want it to find automatically .. i will update my code

Comment: Ar you looking for an expected result? example if I put in ABCDEFG I will always get out 123 or are these results random?

Comment: Selenium is intended for testing web applications. It drives a real web browser.  It's probably not the right tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ZachReichert yes , you will always get the same result when you blast the protein sequence . i want to find a link with the desired criteria automatically . thank you for your time and interest

Comment: @Keith You could be correct , i am learning selenium and i think this tool could do much more than only test .

Comment: @Keith is correct it is a testing tool.  I would agree with him that this is not the correct tool for you.

Comment: If you  want to just see if a link is present you can just execute the "driver.find_element" if it succeds its there if it fails its not I will post an example in an answer.  my answer is in the ruby language though - sorry I dont know python

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
   $driver.find_element(:link, "3RGK_A")
   puts "I found the link"
rescue
   puts "I couldn't find the link"
end
```

Comment: the downside is that this will succeed with any link that matches the pattern of (:link, "3RGK_A")